# SQLitedatabase methods error

Tags: android, sqlite

I am new in android nd am learning SQLitedatabase. am trying to make a new database.why "openorcreatedatabese()" method in this code isnt known familiar nd has error.
what about getApplicationContext() method in toast.maketext()??

```
package com.example.sqlite_tutorial;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyDatabase {

String DATABASE_NAME="DATABASE";
String TABLE_NAME="MY_TABLE";
String DATABASE_CREATE="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS"+TABLE_NAME+
        "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, NAME TEXT,CITY TEXT);";

try {
    SQLiteDatabase mydb=openOrCreateDatabase(DATABASE_NAME,
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE,null);
    mydb.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
}
catch(Exception e){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error in creating table",
          Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();             
}
```

}

Comment: If you have an error you should post it here. For learning SQLite in Android follow this tutorial http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're not calling it on a Context object. For example, inside your Activity you can access those methods, because Activity extends Context, but not in some arbitrary class. Instead, use this:

```
public final class MyDatabase {

    static String DATABASE_NAME="DATABASE";
    static String TABLE_NAME="MY_TABLE";
    static String DATABASE_CREATE="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS"+TABLE_NAME+
            "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, NAME TEXT,CITY TEXT);";

    public static void createDatabase(Context context) {
        try {
            SQLiteDatabase mydb = context.openOrCreateDatabase(DATABASE_NAME,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE,null);
            mydb.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
        } catch(Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(context, "Error in creating table",
                  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();             
        }
    }
}
```

Call MyDatabase.createDatabase(this) inside your acitivity.

Comment: You can directly call it from an activity, a service or a fragment. You do not create any instance (that's why I declared everything as static for you -- creating an instance is a bit pointless here in my opinion). If my answer helped you, would you kindly accept it? :) You accept an answer by clicking the tick below the arrow-down on the left side of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

This may be your solution.

```
 public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static int DB_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DB_NAME = "simpleUser.sql";
    private static DbHelper instance;

    public DbHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
        }
    public static synchronized DbHelper getHelper(Context context) {
            if (instance == null)
                instance = new DbHelper(context);
    return instance;
        }
    @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL(Users.SQL_CREATE);
        }
    @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        }
    }
```